# IN condition within CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have a query that I'm migrating from Postgres (10.1) to Microsoft SQL Server (13.0)

The query working in Postgres in:

```
SELECT * 
FROM source
WHERE
    1 = CASE 
           WHEN 234 NOT IN (SELECT user_id
                            FROM usergroup)
              THEN SOURCE .source_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sl.source_id
                                         FROM sourcelevel SL)
              ELSE 1
        END
```

SQL Server fails with this error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.

This problem seems to stem from the use of an `IN` condition within `CASE/WHEN/ELSE/END`, because if I remove that construct at make the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM source
WHERE
    SOURCE .source_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sl.source_id
                          FROM sourcelevel SL)
```

It executes without error.

Is there some trick to using `IN` syntax inside a `CASE` statement with SQL Server?

Comment: can you try to execute : select CASE WHEN 234 NOT IN(
            SELECT  
                user_id
            FROM
                usergroup  
            )
        THEN
            SOURCE .source_id IN(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    sl.source_id
                FROM
                sourcelevel SL

            )
        ELSE
            1
        END  from source

Comment: I suspect the question may not be framed right as its a very strange query. Is 234 a hardcoded value or the current userid? As I read the query it checks whether 234 is in the usergroup table, completely unrelated to the source table, and if so checks if the courseid is in the sourcelevel table. A definition of the tables would help. This can probably be achived with joins, exists clauses, or if statement as per @cursestacker answer.

Comment: @TomC 234 is simply a value used for illustration purposes.  The actual value for a user ID is substituted here by the ORM

Comment: @Black perhaps this code is supposed to mean: _"user is in special group OR access level to this kind of source allows any user to see it"_.

Comment: @IvanStarostin indeed it does, in the full, unredacted query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a `Boolean` data type. You could instead refactor to a nested CASE expression as below, returning 0 or 1:

```
SELECT * from source
WHERE
    1 =
         CASE WHEN 234 NOT IN(
            SELECT  
                user_id
            FROM
                usergroup  
            )
        THEN
            CASE WHEN SOURCE.source_id IN(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    sl.source_id
                FROM
                sourcelevel SL

            ) THEN 1 
              ELSE 0
             END

        ELSE
            1
        END;
```

I think this could also be refactored without `CASE`, perhaps like:

```
SELECT *
FROM source
WHERE 234 IN(
    SELECT user_id
    FROM usergroup  
    )
    OR 
    SOURCE.source_id IN(
        SELECT sl.source_id
        FROM sourcelevel SL
    );
```

Comment: thank you.  For my understanding, what does the (inner) CASE statement actually return in the above case?  I thought MSSQL used 1 and 0 instead of Boolean true/false

Comment: @Black, the inner CASE expression returns `integer` 1 when the `SOURCE.source_id` value is returned by the subquery, otherwise 0, where it is then returned as the result of the outer `CASE` for use by the `1 =` predicate. It is true (no pun intended) that 0/1/NULL are commonly used to represent Boolean values in SQL Server (like the first example in my answer) and a `bit` type often used to store Boolean representations. The Boolean result of your original `SOURCE .source_id IN (…)` can be evaluated in a predicate but not returned directly as result of the CASE expression.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the `NOT IN` part but on this:

```
THEN SOURCE .source_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sl.source_id
                           FROM sourcelevel SL)
```

I don't know about PostgreSQL but SQL Server definitely doesn't support this condition:

```
WHERE 1 = SOURCE.source_id IN (SELECT..
```

Analyzing your query carefully..

```
SELECT * 
FROM source
WHERE 1 = (CASE WHEN 234 NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM usergroup)
                   THEN SOURCE.source_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sl.source_id FROM sourcelevel AS SL)
                   ELSE 1
           END)
```

It seems that the query simply limits the result of the query if the user ID is not part of the usergroup.

Replacing the `CASE` by `IF` (because `CASE` won't work as the outer part of a query)

```
IF (SELECT user_id FROM usergroup WHERE user_id = 234) IS NULL  
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM source
    WHERE source.source_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sl.source_id FROM sourcelevel AS SL)
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM source
END
```

Comment: Thanks @marc_s I forgot how to format the code. I kept using ` then felt today that I'm forgetting something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this resolves down to this - with @u being your user id parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM source
WHERE exists(select * from usergroup where user_id=@u)
or exists(select * from sourcelevel sl where sl.source_id=source.Sourceid)
```